# LiquidCrystal_I2C, lcd.begin() causes runtime error on Arduino Mega2560

Tags: i2c, lcd, atmega2560

I have tested the library and LCD with simple script and everything worked fine. Now I am trying to add the LCD functionality to my working program but the code reaches the lcd.begin(); function it causes a runtime error and no following lines are executed. I have tried many different configurations and none of them have worked; including have lcd.begin() in the setup(), in the InitSM(), loop(), and RunSM() and it crashes every time.

I am wondering if I am running into a similar issue described [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23168/library-liquidcrystal-i2c-dont-work-in-other-class-composition).

Following thebusybee's advice, I started with a simple working script that could print to the LCD screen. I then started adding initializing functions in the setup until it stopped working. `InitSM(&AFC);` is the line that causes the LCD functions to stop working. `InitSM(&AFC);` calls millis(), enables watchdog timer interrupts, and external interrupt on digital pin 2. Below is the exam code.

```
// Library 
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EventTimers.h>
#include <EventCheckers.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <Timeout.h>
#include <AFCSM.h>
#include <DoorServo.h>
#include <EventTypes.h>
#include <HardwareInterrupts.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);
//LiquidCrystal_I2C *lcdA; //0x27,20,4
//lcdA = &lcd;
//lcdA->begin();

// global variables
static uint8_t TimerCheck = 0;
static uint8_t Timer30; 
static EventType LCDButton;
static EventType BatteryEvents;
static EventType BumperEvents;
static EventType FogEvents;
static EventType CurrentEvent;
static EventType FrontDoor;
static EventType BackDoor;
static AFCDATA AFC;
static AFCState PreviousState;

void setup() {
  // set up serial communication with computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // uart for MiniOFS to MCU
  Serial1.begin(1200, SERIAL_8N1);

  /*** set up interrupts, not init ***/  
  SetUpWatchdogT(); // 8sec interrval counter for 32sec environ sensor check
  SetUpButtonInt(); // external button interrupt for LCD screen

  // init LCD
  lcd.begin();

  // Enable interrupts
  sei();

  // Set the sleep mode to Power-Down
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

  // initi doors
  initDoor();

  // init statemachine
  InitSM(&AFC);
  PreviousState = AFC.State;
}

void loop() {
  Serial.flush();

  lcd.clear();
  // lcd.setCursor(2,0);   //Set cursor to character 2 on line 0
  lcd.print("LED INIT!");
  Serial.println("printed");
}

ISR(WDT_vect) {
  // Add to timer
  TimerCheck += 1;

  // check if 30secs have elapsed time has
  if (TimerCheck >= 3){
    TimerCheck = 0; // reset counter
    Timer30 = true; // raise flag
  }  

}

void Buttonisr(){
  // Button Flag
  LCDButton = BUTTON_ON;
}
```

I narrowed it down to being the external interrupt enable on digital pin 2. Below are the functions for the setup and enable of the external interrupt.

```
void SetUpButtonInt(){
    
    // set up the pin as an input and attach a isr 
    pinMode(ButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ButtonPin), Buttonisr, RISING); // interrupt on rising edge of pin

    return; 
}

void EnableButtonInt(){

    EIMSK |= (1 << INT0); // enable external interrupt
    Serial.println("enable external interrupt");
    return;
}
```

How can this setup affect the lcd I2C setup?

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and format your code, it is easy. Then add the specific error message or explain what you mean by "_runtime error_". To help us help you, minimize your program to the absolute minimum that still shows the erroneous behavior.

Comment: Initialize the LCD only once in setup and not with every update

Comment: @KIIV I tried this first and it would never make it past setup

Comment: If you suspect the line `lcdA->begin();` to crash your program, PLEASE write a minimized sketch just with this initialization in `setup()` and an experimental output. I don't think anyone will rebuild your full hardware setup and debug the complete thing. Investigate step by step. Please [edit] your question and add this minimal sketch and its outcome.

Comment: Just a guess. The minimum timeout for the watchdog timer is 16ms. This `lcd.begin()` may well block for longer than that since the begin method if filled with delay() statements. Just for a test, replace `lcd.begin()` with delay(1000) to see if you get the same symptoms. Where, incidentally,  is this defined: `SetUpWatchdogT()`